# Closet door has light switch in it that needs repair/replacement. How should i go about repairing it?

Tags: electrical, closet

In one of the condos that I manage  has a closet door in one of the bedrooms that needs its light switch repaired/replaced. It's basically a door activated light switch that when the door opens the light turns on and whenever I close the door it turns off. I removed the switch and the wires are still out. The image with a blue circle is the one what it would look basically (regardless of the paint) with it put back in and ready for use. The item that im holding in the 1st photo is the switch for whenever the door opens or closes. Any suggestions as to how i should go about repairing this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Repair what, precisely? You're showing us what appears to be a brand new switch, partially dismantled, the wiring from another removed switch & one in situ [with no indication as to whether that's broken or just another example.] The new switch seems to be a panel mount… with no attendant panel.

Comment: In a condo, which signifies a "Multiple Dwelling Unit" occupancy, you should have a **licensed electrician** replace it with a new one. It is broadly illegal for random unlicensed persons to work on the electrical in such an occupancy, due to the larger risk to life (.vs. single-owner freestanding houses) from fires in one. The lack of a junction box suggests that the installation may already be a code violation without that detail being included, as well.

Comment: to the first comment the first photo was removed from the what's in the 2nd photo as it was not working anymore. What you see in the 3rd photo is basically how it's supposed to look when it's put together and good for use.

Comment: Is this mains-voltage wiring?   I'd suggest upgrading the closet light to 12V DC with LEDs, and then it does not (generally) require an electrician.   Expect to do this across all units.

Answer (score 12):

I speculate from the fact that you refer to the occupancy as a condo that you're in a North American location, as that terminology does not seem to be in widespread use elsewhere, where they get called apartments or flats whether owned or rented.

In the USA, presumably also in Canada, and perhaps not Mexico(?) being a condo owner, manager or maintenance person does not (by itself) make you qualified to work on the electricity in a condo, as they are Multiple Dwelling Units and Electrical code requires that work in such occupancies, where a large number of persons are at risk from a fire shall be done only by Licensed Electricians.

Apart from that, the lack of any electrical box enclosing the wiring at the switch and providing arc containment and strain relief to the wires and/or cables is a code violation all by itself, and implies that the original installation was not done by a licensed electrician. If this is consistent across all or many of the units, it will be a major task to bring it up to code; if it is **not** brought up to code and a fire results, it will void insurance coverage, and incur liability, typically.

Comment: I'm located in north America and in the United States to be more specific. This is good all good to know

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for one of these?

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Gardner-Bender-GSW-SK-Electrical-Normally/dp/B00004WLKL/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=automatic%2Bcloset%2Blight%2Bswitch&qid=1703964777&sr=8-5&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004WLKL)

Comment: Something along those lines yes. Regardless a professional is something I'm considering to get this issue resolved